# Using curl to retrieve prices from Oanda (trading platform)

Tags: bash, curl, terminal, authorization, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to access prices from Oanda using the terminal.

The code that is given by Oanda http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/rates/#getCurrentPrices to retrieve the prices is `curl X GET "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD%2CUSD_JPY%2CEUR_CAD"`,
however when I key this into the terminal, the response I get is:

```
    "code" : 3,
    "message" : "This request requires authorization",
    "moreInfo" : "http:\/\/developer.oanda.com\/docs\/v1\/auth\/#overview"
```

I understand that the error stems from the need for authorization and from the website, `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx" https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/accounts`

As such, I'd like to enquire what should I key into the terminal such that I can retrieve the prices from Oanda since authorization and price retrieval are two distinct instructions in `curl` as given by the website. I know that it is achievable in python through the usage of requests, just wondering how it is manageable through `curl` since I am relatively new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Oanda but it seems like they are using OAuth2 to secure their web-service. According to their [doc](http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live/authentication/), you should be able to generate a "Personal Access Token" via their UI (My Account -> My Services -> Manage API Access).

Once you get such a token, you should be able to call their web-service like so:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer yourpersonalaccesstoken" -X GET "https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD%2CUSD_JPY%2CEUR_CAD"
```

Comment: thank you. I have the token, just uncertain how to go about calling it through curl the terminal. I've tried your method, entering :
    curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx-xxxxxxx” -X GET "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD%2CUSD_JPY%2CEUR_CAD” however i received: curl: no URL specified. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your curl command may not be propertly formatted. In your comment you're missing the http://. Can you try copy / pasting the exact example from my answer in a terminal and replacing yourpersonalaccesstoken with your token?

Comment: Cheers, it worked! Appreciate it! Didn't know it is achievable via concatenating the codes. I believe that I must have keyed in something incorrectly previously. Would appreciate it if you could direct me to some good sources to learn more about curl too. Regardless, thanks again!

Comment: The official curl website has some good documentation. Check out https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html. Otherwise the man pages are very detailed (type "man curl" in a terminal).